# Pass code as function argument in javascript?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I'm trying to create a javascript framework by myself(so no jquery,mootools... code please) and I want to make the code for my framework only accessible in a framework function so for example, something like this:

```
frameworkname({
//framework code here
});
```

so my framework code doesn't conflict with other frameworks. I know that `frameworkname({});` is a function, but I don't know how you pass code as a function argument. I know this is possible as I'm quite experienced in jquery and jquery has that stuff everywhere (example:`$(document).ready(function(){//codehere});`), but how did the jquery developers do this? I want to be able to do this for my framework. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just look at the jQuery source?

Comment: Oh boy, now that's a misconception... I begin to sympathize with the people complaining about using jQuery for everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Functions are first class objects in JavaScript. You can pass them around in the same way as Strings, Numbers, Arrays or any other data type.

```
var foo = function () { alert(1); };
var bar = function (arg) { arg(); }
bar(foo);
```

Comment: thanks, that answers most of it. But I understand to do this you have to write something like this: `bar(function(){//code});`. Is there anyway to do this:`bar({//code});`

Comment: Thanks, well, that answers that. Thanks for all the help! I'll mark yours as answer once I can

Answer (score 1):

in javascript, a function is exactly a variable, the code you mentioned:

```
$(document).ready( function () {//code});
```

is in fact declared a function without a name, and then passed it as an argument to "ready()".
Thus, your mind of pass code to function in the way

```
frameworkname( {} );
```

is illegal because "{}" is a code block but not any kind of "variable"

Comment: It's not illegal. It just passes a blank object. Also, you seem to confuse variables with values/objects.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, variables can represent any data type. Therefore, in `function frameworkname( x ) { }` can take an argument of any type (function, object, primitive, etc).

```
function frameworkname( x ) {
    if ( typeof x === "function" ) {
        x(); // function passed
    } else if ( typeof x === "object" ) {
        for ( var i in x ) {
           // Object passed
           x[i]();
        }
    }
}
frameworkname(function() {
    alert("function passed as argument");
});
frameworkname({
    hello: function() {
         alert("hello");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
function frameworkname(){

  this.ready = function(code){
      code();
  };
  return this;
}

frameworkname().ready(function(){
  console.log('Function executed'); 
});
```