# Change namespaced array name inside function using argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, namespaces

This question looks a little bit like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379106/pass-code-as-function-argument-in-javascript) but it didn't solve my problem.

I have a namespaced array of objects like `color.blue` (`color` is the namespace and `blue` is the array of objects) and I need to do something like this:

```
var color = {
    red:[],
    blue:[]
}

function foo(arg){
    for(var i = 0; i < arg.length; i++){
        color.arg[i].push(obj);
    }
}
```

So I can add the `obj` object to the namespaced array of objects just by calling this function, but this code throws the error `[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'color.arg[i]')`. I've even tried using `eval()` (with success) but I want to avoid slow/evil code. *Can someone help me?*

**Note that I don't want to write the namespace in the function's arguments, just "red" or "blue"**

[**Here's a JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2e8E/). I want to add the console.log to print `["abc"]` without typing the namespace in the function argument.

Comment: `color[arg[i]].push(obj);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a property name comes from a variable, you need the bracket syntax to select it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
    if (color.hasOwnProperty(arg[i])) {
        color[arg[i]].push(obj);
    }
}
```

The additional condition prevents an error from occurring when you do `foo('orange');`

#### Update

```
var color = {
    red: []
}, obj = "abc";

function addObjToArray(arr){
    color[arr].push(obj);
}
addObjToArray(red);

console.log(color.red);
```

In the code, the `addObjToArray()` is called with an uninitialised variable `red`; you need to use a string literal:

```
addObjToArray('red');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2e8E/1/)

Comment: I think I didn't explained my question correctly, then I've created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2e8E/ I want the console.log to print ["abc"] without typing "color" in the function argument.

Answer (score 1):

The object `color` has no member named `arg`. Instead of:

```
color.arg[i].push(obj)
```

... you probably want:

```
var colorName = arg[i];
color[colorName].push(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
color[arg[i]].push(obj);
```

`color.arg` is literally looking for a property named `arg`, in `color`. Instead, you want it to reference the property with the name that is in `arg`, which is what the bracket notation is used for.

So, for example, if `arg == ["red", "green", "blue"]`, then `color[arg[2]]` will point to the same property as `color.blue`.